# Problem with CSRF protected Login in Cypress

Tags: authentication, cypress

I try to test a PHP Symfony application via Cypress.io but got problems with a custom login command which uses CSRF protection.

My command looks like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
    cy.request('/login')
        .its('body')
        .then((body) => {
            const $html = Cypress.$(body);
            const csrf = $html.find('input[name=_csrf_token]').val();

            cy.request({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/login',
                failOnStatusCode: false,
                form: true,
                body: {
                    username: 'user',
                    password: 'password',
                    _csrf_token: csrf,
                },
            })
        });
});
```

This is the test spec:

```js
describe('Masterdata Test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login();
        cy.visit('/masterdata/autoselector');
    });

    it('highlights the correct register', () => {
        cy.get('.registerTab.bg-white').contains('Masterdata');
    });
});
```

When I run the tests it seems that the login somehow works (it returns a 200 status code) but when it visits the url which should be checked it redirects to login again. (See picture below)

[image]

I already checked that the CSRF token is correct and I also removed the whole CSRF protection from the login and only used the second `cy.request` call in my login command and it worked just fine.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

The below code worked for me,

PS: Only for UI based login.

```js
before(() => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.get(/*<get the webelement for csrf token>*/).invoke('attr', 'value').then(($value) => {
        cy.setCookie('csrftoken', $value);
    });
});

beforeEach(() => {
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('csrftoken');
});
```

Comment: @stedekay Can you mark this answer as `Accepted` if it worked for you?

Comment: Could you explain why the cookie needs to be set with the token? I can't see in the normal flow that it's set in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the CSRF Tokens demo in the Cypress Recipes repo.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens

Comment: Yeah, I know this resource and used the way to get the token from the HTML. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: same here! i cannot make it run, and the demo is broken out-of-the-box :/

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem: The form would just reload without any error.

Turns out for me this happened because php sessions in Symfony where not working with `APP_ENV=test` and therefore the csrf token would change on every request ;-) I had to switch to `dev` or `prod` and then it worked just fine.

I discovered this by testing if the csfr token would be the same between reloads:

```
describe('Check csrf', () => {
    it('Grabs Token and reloads', () => {
        // get csrf token and output to command log
        cy.request('/login')
        .its('body')
        .then((body) => {
        const $html = Cypress.$(body)
        const csrf = $html.find('input[name=_csrf_token]').val()
        cy.log(csrf)
        })

        // do the same again
        cy.request('/login')
        .its('body')
        .then((body) => {
        const $html = Cypress.$(body)
        const csrf = $html.find('input[name=_csrf_token]').val()
        cy.log(csrf)
        })
    })
})
```